# How to add HAProxy package into bitbake recipe

Tags: haproxy, recipe, bitbake

I am new to bitbake recipe. I am trying to add HAProxy package into bitbake. I am trying to create a recipe but not sure how to proceed with it. 
so far I have just made it till here:

```
SUMMARY = "HAProxy support for NEXT"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.haproxy.org/"
SECTION = "tools"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2d862e836f92129cdc0ecccc54eed5e0"

SRC_URI = "http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/src/haproxy-${PV}.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "3362d1e268c78155c2474cb73e7f03f9"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "fd06b45054cde2c69cb3322dfdd8a4bcfc46eb9d0c4b36d20d3ea19d84e338a7"
```

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Answer (score -1):

haproxy is a Makefile based project, so this link should help:

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-makefile-based-package

You should define this variable in your recipe:

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE = "TARGET=XXX"
```

replacing XXX by the target your are interested (generic, linux22, linux24, and so on). That string TARGET=XXX will be passed as argument to the 'make' command, so bitbake will start compilation. Most probably that's all you need.